# jQuery lambda functions

Tags: asp.net, jquery, visual-studio-2008, lambda, javascript

jQuery uses lambda functions extensively wherever a function is to be passed into another function. But Visual Studio 2008 would not honor break points that are set inside a JavaScript lambda function. Anybody knows any workaround for this other than giving an explicit name for the function and passing this to the jQuery functions?

Answer (score 4):

try using [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843).

Comment: Chrome's debugger is fairly nice too. The only disadvantage I can think of is that you'll get an inaccurate impression of how fast your code will run for most people :)

Answer (score 0):

Put **debugger** statement into your function.

```
$.get('http://...').on('data', 
    function(data) {
        debugger;
    }
);
```