# Can I use lambda expressions in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lambda, anonymous-function

In [jQuery lambda functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667841/jquery-lambda-functions), the user asks about debugging lambda expressions in JQuery.  I've searched many sites, and I'm unable to find examples of lambda expressions in JQuery.  Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so where can I find some examples?

Comment: You may want to go into more detail about what you want to do, perhaps with some pseudo-code, to clarify your question.

Answer (score 7):

Lambda expression are used (among other things) as a shorthand to specifying [anonymous functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) (also called anonymous delegates or anonymous methods).  That is, pointers to function that you define on-the-fly.

See this common JQuery Ajax example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    $(this).addClass("done");
  } });
```

The *success* parameter uses Javascript's on-the-fly function definition and pointer.  **So yes, there is a kindof lambda syntax for anonymous function in javascript**.  In fact, this is very similar to [VB.NET's lambda syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163362.aspx), used very powerfully for both expression trees and anonymous functions:

```
Dim newNinjaList = NinjaList.Where(Function(n) n.primaryWeapon = "dagger")
```

So, you could say there's a lambda syntax in JQuery, though many would consider it inelegant.

If you mean lambda expressions to specify [expression trees](http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus5/html/page264.html), then the answer is simple:  **no, JQuery does not use any kind of lambda syntax for expression trees**.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript doesn't really have lambda expressions, because you have to explicitly return a value. Some languages like ruby automatically return the value of the last statement, but in JavaScript this doesn't work:

```
var double = function(i) { i * 2; }
var x = double(5);
```

But if you add the return in there it works.

```
var double = function(i) { return i * 2; }
```

Comment: Nitpicky: You don't actually have to explicitly return a value. If you call a function with the `new` operator, then an object is automatically created based on that function's prototype, and said object is automatically returned. In other contexts, the value `undefined` is automatically returned.

Comment: Oh, but that's probably not what you meant.

Comment: True but lambda expressions would normally want to return primitives like ints or strings. For objects, sure, constructor form might be a way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The term you are looking for in JS is "anonymous function", e.g.

```
$(function() { 
    /* in an anonymous function that is passed 
       to the jQuery document ready handler */ 
 });
```

Specifically, the anonymous function part is the

```
function() { /* whatever */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the advent of ECMAScript 6 (in June 2015), you can use the "arrow operator", and thus this works:

```
$(()=>{
  alert("Hello arrow.");
});
```

... at least in modern-day Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Opera, according to https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-arrow_functions.

Note that the arrow functionality doesn't set "this" in the called functions, so they're not very good as event handlers, compared to good old anonymous functions:

```
<a href="#">Click me</a>
<script>
  $('a[href="#"]')
    // arrow function: 
    .click((event)=>{
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("arrow: "+(this==window)); // 'this' is window, not the <a>.
    })
    // anonymous function:
    .click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("anonymous: "+this.tagName); // 'this' is <a>.
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
lstResource.find(x => x.Module == Module && x.Form == Form && x.ResourceName == Resource).Value
```

Except for IE, it will work for every place.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is an extension of the Javascript programming language. To my knowledge there is no lambda support in javascript. what you see is not really lambda expression but function chaining and passing functions as first class objects, much like Func. Lambdas are not in javascript language spec.

Comment: What's the difference? They are not called lambdas, but they are a part of the language. A lambda is just a fancy name for an anonymous function. Or is there some difference I'm forgetting?

Comment: Lambdas are more of on-the-fly functions. What I meant was that the support for writing something like " x such that x*2 " is absent. You could even pass functions and chain method calls in C. They werent lambas IMO. Your take "lambdas are fancy anonymous function" is in a way correct.

Comment: here is Mr Lippert's article about the same http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/01/10/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-one.aspx

Comment: lambdas always return. ergo, an anonymous function is a little different conceptually, but since in js all non-returning functions actually return undefined, you could argue that all js functions _are_ lambdas

Answer (score 0):

I think they refer to a vanilla callback syntax and the specific problem they have is to do with how Visual Studio debugs JavaScript.

That's what I think they are referring to as a 'lambda'

```
$.get('http://...').on('data', 
    function(data) {
        ...
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the http://jslinq.codeplex.com/ project.  While this does not actually bring a true lambda syntax to javascript, it allows you to use the `linq` extension methods (such as `where`, `orderby`, etc) on anything that is an array.

Answer (score 0):

yah, but arrow do not work in IE11, as "let".
http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

```
$("#CountrySelect").on("change", "#countrySelect", null, e => {
let that = $(e.target); //$(this);
if (that.val() !== "" && window.localStorage) {
    localStorage.setItem("countrySelect", String(that.val()));
}

if (that.val()) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: urlControlSwitchLanguage,
        data: {
            language: that.val()
        },
        success: (data) => {
            if ("error" in data) {
                $("#mainDataBodyTable").empty();
                $("#mainDataBodyTable").append(`<div>${data.error}</div>`);
                console.error(data.error);
            } else {
                $("#mainDataBodyTable").empty();
                countTableElement = createTable$(data, countTableElement);
                $("#linkDownloads").attr("href", urlControlGetFile + "?language=" + that.val());
            }
        },
        error: (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) => {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(ajaxOptions);
            console.log(thrownError);
        }
    });
}
```